# Is it possible using pyexiv2 with python3 on MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyexiv2

I need to get metadata from images, the best lib pyexiv2, but i can't install pyexiv2 in python3, Do you have any recommendation?

[image]

Comment: have you tried to run the installation as root? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202035

Comment: Yes i did as root

Comment: do you have all dependencies? https://python3-exiv2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developers.html#dependencies

Comment: yeap i did, my problem is i can't test my code on my macbook, i can run on windows,